# Зависает listener Oracle11r2

Tags: linux, oracle

Суть проблемы такова, при запуске сервера через определенный промежуток времени что-то происходит с БД, tnsping может занимать до 4 минут и выше, при рестарте listener'a все нормализуется на какое-то время и затем все по новой, только время между перезапусками уменьшается, решив что проблема в листенере я пересоздал файлик менеджером netca, проблема вроде как решилась. Но придя с утра после выходных был удивлен тем что часть ПО работает а часть нет, просто не может подключиться к серверу. tnsping 0-10ms долго ломал голову но когда перезагрузил полностью машину, все приложения удачно подключились к БД. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать ? в чем может быть беда ? может какая-то из сессий ложить БД ? могут ли view или тригеры ложить БД ? при просмотре сессий:

```
select * from v$session
```

ничего подозрительного не увидел, не знаю что и думать. ОС : CentOS 7. Спасибо.

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но, спрошу, вы смотрели, достаточно ли свободного места на сервере (на диске с ораклом, диск с логами, и прочие диски, которые используются непосредственно ораклом)?

Comment: "часть ПО работает, а часть нет" - а какая работает, а какая нет. В чём между ними разница? Если вы подозревали прослушку, что показал diff между старой и новой конфигурацией? Вопрос @test123 о наличии места на дисках имеет основания, если включено логирование в прослушивателе  и нет места, куда логи писать, он откажется обрабатывать запросы  пока место не появится.  И на заметку tnsping не проверяет базу, а только соединение с прослушкой, база может быть вообще выключена.

Comment: @0xdb разница в драйвере через который происходит соединение. Про diff можно подробнее я немного не вкурсе что это и как это использовать. По поводу места на диске, на данный момент ещё в доступе 800 Гб думаю этого достаточно. По поводу логирования вкурсе данного поведения БД при переполнениях. Поэтому первым делом было все вычещенно т.к файл с логами был около 4Гб. Да конечно я понимаю что tnping  проверяет только прослушку. Но БД была запущена или вы намекает что проблема может быть с БД ???

Comment: @Ethernets Разницу в драйвере мы уже обсуждали, насколько я припоминаю.  С diff я имел в виду разницу между новой и старой конфигурацией прослушивателя (netca оставляет старую конф. listener.ora.bak; diff  - утилитка, которая показывает  разницу между двумя файликами) .  А какие в настоящее время проблемы? Всё же вроде работает.

Comment: @0xdb да, с момента пересоздания listener'a по сегодняшний день работоспособность не нарушалась. Конфиги если честно ничем не отличаются, я конечно завтра еще раз посмотрю на работе. Но мне тогда не понятно следующее почему когда те абоненты которые пытались подключиться к БД и не смогли, на самом сервере был запущен tnsping localhost и время так же от 4-х и выше минут. Не странное ли поведение БД ? какова вероятность повторения ?

Comment: @0xdb Вообще не понятно что могло спровоцировать такое поведение БД ? Перезагрузка сервера полностью, помогала лишь на небольшой интервал времени

Comment: Если  tnsping с явной задержкой, то надо смотреть в логах listener-a. Если там ничего подозрительного, то это сетевые проблемы. Да, и посмотрите, включен ли IP6, насколько я припоминаю, listener пока его не понимает.  И ещё раз, к БД это всё отношения не имеет.

Comment: @0xdb Какие могут быть сетевые проблемы на самом сервере где стоит база ? Ведь на нем так же задержка была. В логах проблем и ошибок замечено не было. Спасибо за ваш ответ, если что-то опять произойдет возобновлю тему.